# How To Add Indices Together Within An Array?

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment and I'm not sure how to add the indices together to get a sum that can be displayed. Mind you I'm only a high school student so my code is sloppier and less efficient than what any of you would likely create, but any help is appreciated. Here's what I have right now that's producing an index out of bounds exception:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the amount of workers you have");
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
        int workerAmount = userInput.nextInt();
        int payroll[][]= new int [workerAmount][6];
         for(int a = 0; a < payroll.length; a++){
          for(int b = 0; b < payroll[a].length; b++)
           {

            System.out.println("How many hours did this worker work?");
            Scanner use = new Scanner (System.in);
            int user = use.nextInt();
            payroll[a][b] = user;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < payroll.length; i++){
        for(int a = 0; a < payroll[i].length; a++){
            System.out.println(payroll[i][a]);
            int sum = (payroll[i + a][a]); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `sum` supposed to represent? The total number of hours worked in a week?

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the lazy and non-descriptive code

Comment: this is most likely the cause of indexOutOfBounds --> `int sum = (payroll[i + a][a]); `

Comment: It's hard to tell what you were trying to do on that line without a better description. Sum the hours worked for each employee?

Comment: Is there any way to correct this? Eclipse is telling me that's where it is, but I have no idea how to add the indices within an array

Comment: @ShawnBrown you want to add all the numbers inside the two-dimensional array into one sum?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw , yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to sum all the values, try this:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < payroll.length; i++){
    for(int a = 0; a < payroll[i].length; a++){
       sum += payroll[i][a];
    }
}

System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);
```

The code above simply iterates through all the arrays of arrays and adds the value of each element onto the `sum` variable which then gets printed to the console.

Comment: This displayed all my entered values for the worker's hours, didn't add them together, but thank you

Comment: @ShawnBrown that's because you have the println inside the loop. remove it. just copy the answer and paste it as it is.

Comment: Never mind, I'm stupid and forgot to paste the println, thank you very much, it worked!

Comment: @ShawnBrown don't forget to accept answer if it has helped.

Comment: Gimme a sec until it allows me to but thank you very much!

Comment: I did not downvote, but you should not boast about fixing bad code when your answer does not include any explanation :-)

Comment: @GhostCat will do in a few minutes ;). taking a quick break.